# Calling DOMDocument()->load get eternal time loading page

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have a custom RSS parser, but I have a problem with it:

Here's my code:

```
$RSS_options = array(
        'http' => array(
                'method' => 'GET',
                'timeout' => '1'
        ));

function RSS_Retrieve( $urls = array() )
{
        global $RSS_Content, $RSS_options;

        $context = stream_context_create($RSS_options);
        $RSS_Content = array();

        foreach ( $urls as $key => $url )
        {
                libxml_set_streams_context($context);
                $doc_[$key]  = new DOMDocument();
                @$doc_[$key]->load( $url );
                $channels_[$key] = $doc_[$key]->getElementsByTagName("channel");

                foreach( $channels_[$key] as $channel )
                {
                        RSS_Channel( $channel, $key );
                }
        }

}
```

(These code are called 4 times, first one with 3 URLs, the other 3 with only one url each time).

Now, the problem:

The host being called is down now. The page load times are triggering a 504 gateway timeout (because PHP are reaching max execution time).

I've tried to create the conext $RSS_options, for configuring a timeout for DOMDocument. But I think PHP are not reading these setting for DOMDocument.

I know if I fix the URLs for working ones the page works correctly. But I think, before this, I need to make something for the case of a failure connecting.

How can I set a timeout loading these URLs with DOMDocument? (I've used 1 on my example for triggering the timeout really fast, for testing purposes)